# Can I change the system bell noise in Exceed?

Tags: exceed

I'm using Hummingbird Exceed to xterm to a unix box.  The xterm and gvim both use the system bell often.  Unfortunately this is reproduced as a full volume beep in my headphones as well as the exceed tab on the task bar (not the program's tab) being highlighted.

Is there a way to adjust this behavior, at least so I don't go deaf?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Exceed, but you can turn on the visual bell in `xterm` to make the window flash instead of having an audible bell:

```
xterm -vb
```

or Ctrl-Mouse-Button-2 and select "Enable Visual Bell".